# Disabling all elements of a form in HTML except Submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Is there any way to **disable** the elements of a form `onload`, except the submit button.

It means that form in JSP page will be loaded with the existing data from backend but user should not be able to edit data. User can only use the submit the button.

I can do it manually by disabling each and every field manually but I am wondering if there is some way to disable all fields at a time, since there are many fields in the form in JSP page.

Comment: I don't see the point of submiting a form with disabled fields... Also using user-input fields and disabling input on all those fields is defeating the pupose of input fields. If you need your user to validate some data (which  is one of the reasons I see to implement the solution you ask for), just display it to him without using form fields...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector

```
$('form :not([type=submit])').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Is this possible using form id's if I have multiple forms in one page

Comment: @AnooshaNarava : off course you can ., try `$('#form-id :not([type=submit])').prop('disabled',true);`